# PHP json_encode won't output proper result

Tags: php, json

I want to output users via a json object but when I try to output their songs list it only outputs the last one. I want to get this list into an array.

this is my array push while looping through users,

```
array_push($arrayUsers, array(
               'username' => $user['username'],
               'id' => $user['_id'],
               'favSongs' => array(
                    'title' =>'song1',
                    'title' =>'song2'
                    )
               )
          );
```

but this is what I get back (missing song title),

```
[{"username":"asdfasdfasd","id":{"$id":"4f58d7227edae19c02000000"},"songs":{"title":"song2"}}]
```

I want it to output the songs like this, but am confused how to get it to do this using PHP:

```
"songs":[{"title": "song1"}, {"title": "song2"}]
```

Comment: `array('title' =>'song1','title' =>'song2')` is not a valid array - or rather it is valid but you cannot have two of the same key without always overwriting one.

Comment: Instead, just use a plain numeric array for those `'favSongs' => array('song1','song2')`

Comment: ohhh I get it now! Thanks I tried this and it worked `array_push($arrayUsers, array('username' => $user['username'], 'id' => $user['_id'], 'favSongs' => array(array('title' =>'song1'), array('title' =>'song3'))));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'favSongs' => array(
   'title' => 'song1',
   'title' => 'song2'
)
```

PHP will replace the 'title' key with the last one declared.

```
"songs":[{"title": "song1"}, {"title": "song2"}]
```

This is an array of objects, so in PHP it needs to be an array of arrays.

```
'favSongs' => array(
   array('title' => 'song1'),
   array('title' => 'song2')
)
```